# Duda sobre bucle for

Tags: c++

llevo dos semanas,hay un ejercicio donde el programa tiene que decir la temperatura mas baja y la mas alta de todas las que les hayas puesto, como se haria? . Muchas gracias.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
 float t1,temperatura_media,t2,t3,t4;
int main(){
    for(int x=0;x<1;x++){
        cout<<"Pon la temperatura 00:00: ";cin>>t1;
        cout<<"Pon la temperatura 06:00: ";cin>>t2;
        cout<<"Pon la temperatura 12:00: ";cin>>t3;
        cout<<"Pon la temperatura 18:00: ";cin>>t4;

    }
    temperatura_media= (t1+t2+t3+t4)/4;
    cout<<"la temperatura media es: "<<temperatura_media<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: soy nuevo, por eso esta duda tan de principiante.

Comment: Y probaste comparar las temperaturas? si, el ejercicio es basico, y por ahi te falta un empujon, mas que alguien escriba el codigo por vos. Que probaste por ejemplo para la temperatura mas baja?? (la mas alta es lo mismo, pero al reves)

Comment: Metes los valores en un array, lo ordenas y la temperatura mayor y menos están en los extremos.

Answer (score 0):

No se exactamente por que metes los count dentro de un for que solo se ejecuta una vez. Es ilogico. Pero en fín, para lo que necesitas hacer existen muchas formas, algunas incluyen uso de estructuras, arrays, vectores o simples condiciones. La más sencilla es hacerlo por condiciones, tipo: `if(t1>t2)`, pero también es la mas tediosa ya que tienes que considerar todos los casos sin mencionar que es poco eficiente.

La forma más simple y a la vez la que yo considero mas efectiva es la siguiente:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
   float temperaturas[4] = {25.35, 18.40, 21.29, 25.14};
   sort(temperaturas, temperaturas+4);

}
```

Fuente: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sort_%28C%2B%2B%29

Ahora una vez ordenados para obtener la temperatura minima puedes hacerlo con `temperaturas[0]`y la temperatura maxima con `temperaturas[3]`.

Saludos!